# TCP Listener on Elixir using Erlang's gen_tcp module

Tags: tcp, elixir

I am using the following code to create a TCP listener on elixir :

```
defmodule KVServer do
use Application

@doc false
def start(_type, _args) do
  import Supervisor.Spec

  children = [
    supervisor(Task.Supervisor, [[name: KVServer.TaskSupervisor]]),
    worker(Task, [KVServer, :accept, [4040]])
  ]

  opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: KVServer.Supervisor]
  Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
end

@doc """
  Starts accepting connections on the given `port`.
"""
def accept(port) do
  {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(port,
                  [:binary, packet: :line, active: false, reuseaddr:     true])
  IO.puts "Accepting connections on port #{port}"
  loop_acceptor(socket)
end

defp loop_acceptor(socket) do
  {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
  {:ok, pid} = Task.Supervisor.start_child(KVServer.TaskSupervisor, fn -> serve(client) end)
  :ok = :gen_tcp.controlling_process(client, pid)
  loop_acceptor(socket)
end

defp serve(socket) do
  socket
  |> read_line()
  |> write_line(socket)

  serve(socket)
end

defp read_line(socket) do
  {:ok, data} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)
  data
end

defp write_line(line, socket) do
  :gen_tcp.send(socket, line)
end
end
```

It is taken from the following link: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/task-and-gen-tcp.html

When I try to get data from my gps deveice (for which I am writing this piece of code) using :gen_tcp.recv(socket,0), I get an error:
`{:error, reason} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)` and the reason it showed is just "closed".

However, the device is sending data, which I confirmed using a tcp packet sniffer (tcpflow).

Also, when I try to send data using telnet as described in the tutorial above, it works fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Based on the limited description, I'm confused on your setup-  You've got the code for a TCP *server*, but it sounds like you want to access your GPS device over TCP, so you probably want a TCP *client*.   Your `:gen_tcp.recv` call probably says `:closed` because there are no clients connecting to your server.  More details on the setup, please, and hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Hey, I solved that yesterday. However I tried to improve the details to make question more sensible. I actually needed a TCP server only as the device is sending data constantly, and I had to receive that over my server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out. Actually the device was sending raw stream of data not lines of data. So I had to change "packet: :line" parameter in :gen_tcp.listen function to "packet: :raw".

It was working on telnet because telnet sends lines of data (with line breaks).